# Input Button with a default

Tags: excel, vba, button, input

I have a workbook that has 3 work sheets.

1. Keith’s April Monthly Budget
2. web Links
3. CT Scan

I created a Button go to a web site to pay a bill
This is it

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Web Links").Select
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Sheets("Keith's April Monthly Budget").Select
End Sub
```

In the ’**CT Scan**’ sheet I have 4 columns, `Date “A4”`, `Owed”B4”`,`Balance Left “C4”`,`Payed this month “D4”` and `Payments Made “E4”`.

I need an input Button that will allow me  to make a input box to make a  payment of $25.00 or more and put it in the next blank box down from `“D4”`. By the way, the column “Balance Left” is linked to
("`Keith's April Monthly Budget`")

Comment: I added `vb6` tag. If incorrect, please add the correct language tag

Comment: @vidit sorry, I was editing while you added the tag. I changed it to vba because it seems to be Workbook related (aka Excel)

Answer (score 1):

Assign the following macro to that button.

```
Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CT Scan")
        .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp) = InputBox("Enter the amount")
    End With

End Sub
```